# How to query on unanalyzed fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I have a few things in my elasticsearch_dsl class that i want to query for an exact match:

```
class Profile(DocType):
    name = String(fields={'raw': String(index='not_analyzed')})
```

While that does work, i always need to add a `.raw` to the query and cannot query `name` exactly:

```
# Matches "foo" and "foo-1"
Profile.search().filter('term', name='foo'})
# Matches nothing
Profile.search().filter('term', name='foo-1'})
# Matches what i want (only "foo-1")
Profile.search().filter('term', **{'name.raw': 'foo-1'})
```

This feels kinda wrong, as i should be able to just use `name` and not `raw`, because it should be the same.

What's the right way?

Comment: You just need to index your main field as `not_analyzed`, but prefered way would be to have `raw` field as you have it now.

Comment: I did index it as `not_analyzed`, see the DocType class i have attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the correct way to use it is with `name.raw` because that's the field which is `not_analyzed`. If you use only `name` you are not using the `not_analyzed` version, you use the analyzed version with the `standard` analyzer.

That's why `filter('term', name='foo'})` matches both `foo` and `foo-1`.